# Rails (ruby) create empty array when no association found

Tags: ruby, arrays, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, simple-form

So I have this bit of code:

```
= f.input :aspectRatioId, :label => 'Aspect Ratio', 
:input_html => { :id => 'dvd_aspectRatio_tokens', :data => { :load => [@dvd.aspectRatio] } }
```

I'd like to create an empty array when nothing is found in the association. Right now when nothing is found it returns `[null]` which trips up tokeninoput javascript that expects `[]`

I can do this by creating another method like this:

```
def self.series_without_empty_values(dvd)
  series = [dvd.dvd_series]
  if series[0].nil?
    series = []
  end
  return series
end
```

But I would rather do it in the `:load =>` call on the form. Is this even possible?

Comment: you could try `:load => [@dvd.aspectRatio] || []`. Not sure if that will work though.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: No, that won't work, `[nil]` is true-ish, even `[]` is true-ish in Ruby. @kaukebie, that's a weird way to write that condition :-) even if Ruby had no `Array#compact` you'd simply write: `dvd.dvd_series ? [dvd.dvd_series] : []`.

Comment: It's hardly ever necessary to call `.nil?` on an object that will either be defined or not. Use `if (!series[0])` or `unless (series[0])` instead for simplicity. However, as noted in the answers, `compact` is the solution to this problem.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen that won't work, I tried it. @tokland: The ol' ternary operator, I love it but it doesn't work because dvd.dvd_series will not result in false unless I do something like what I'm doint there: `series[0].nil?` anything else would simply not return the empty array.

Comment: @tadman: I actually think that `if series[0].nil?` is a lot more readable than `(!series[0])`. I always miss those `!` :) Thanks for all the suggestions, that's what this site is all about.

Comment: @kakubei There's a lot of things you'll miss until you develop an eye for them. `=` vs `==` is one, and the binding of `&&` vs `and` is another. I prefer `unless` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @tadman: The `=` I'm actually ok with. `&&` vs `and` I'm still on the fence.  But I do prefer `unless`. I think it's a wonderful addition that other languages (I'm looking at you PHP) don't have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array.compact` to remove `nil` values in an array:

```
[ "a", nil, "b", nil, "c", nil ].compact
=> [ "a", "b", "c" ]

[nil].compact
=> []
```

Comment: Good idea, maybe combine it with "empty?": "if series.compact.empty?"

Comment: This is wonderful! I didn't know about this method. Now I can remove all those extra methods! It was really bothering me to have to add ugly hacks. Thanks a lot. (I love Ruby :)

Comment: Check out the `Enumerable` library as it's full of interesting features.